Clarification about varitional autoencoders training
I have one specific question about VAEs as I try to work through the math on my own. I found from this paper that to training a VAE model involves optimizing a lower-bound of the marginal log-likelihood, given by this equation:

They then say that the first term is the Kullback-Leibler divergence and the second term is the variational lower bound given by this:

I'm confused about how the first equation and the second equation relate, and what the first term in the first equation is doing. Is the second equation simply the first one but rearranged in some way? Which one are we trying to optimize? I'm confused because the KL divergence denoted in the first equation is the estimated posterior compared to the true posterior and im assuming we don't have the true posterior so what is this equation doing?? Or do we only care about the second equation for VAE training? Any thoughts on this would be very much appreciated!
